# 64-bit overflow math conversion

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I have a conversion I am trying to perform:

```
uint64_t factor = 2345345345; // Actually calculated at runtime, but roughly this magnitude

uint64_t Convert(uint64_t num)
{
    return num * 1000ULL / factor;
}
```

For the largest `num` values the multiplication wraps before dividing by `factor`.  Changing the order to `num / factor * 1000UL` looses some accuracy that is not acceptable.

I'd like to rewrite `Convert()` to handle all possible `num` values:

```
uint64_t Convert(uint64_t num)
{
    if(num > MAX_UINT64/1000ULL)       // pseudo code
    {
        // Not sure what to put here
    }
    else
    {
        return num * 1000ULL / factor;
    }
}
```

We considered using 128-bit math, but would like to avoid it if possible.

What is the most efficient way to implement `Convert()` so that it can ideally handle the the largest `num` possible and still produce the correct result?

Comment: Do you mean ULL? Or are you using a 32 bit factor for a specific reason?

Comment: @kfsone I changed it to ULL for clarity.

Comment: @kfsone - 1000 is an `int`, which may or may not be 32 bits. Regardless, it gets converted to `uint64_t` in the various places where it's used.

Comment: @PeteBecker 1000 is a *signed* int. 1000UL is an unsigned long int. Explicitly. It may get converted, or it may cause conversions and loss of precision. 1000ULL is explicitly an unsigned long long int. Since he intends it to be an unsigned long long int, it seems reasonable to get the specifier right in the first place, if only for clarity of conveying intent to  any other programmer who reads the code, or himself if he is trying to re-read it while hung over at 4.30am on a sunday morning with the client screaming at him over the phone.

Comment: @kfsone - yes, programmers who are ignorant of how integral types interact in arithmetic expressions may be confused; ignorance can be fixed. This code does **exactly** the same thing, with or without the suffix. The intent, with or without the suffix, is clear: multiply the value by 1000. Of course, if you insist on adding suffixes to protect your drunken self, you'll also need a suffix whenever you add `1` to a value whose type isn't `int`.

Comment: I just noticed that the code in the original question used `1000UL`, not `1000`; it is, in fact, at least 32 bits. But this demonstrates the drawback of adding unnecessary suffixes: you have to maintain them.

Answer (score 3):

A little oldschool **math**, you can use `%` to calculate remain:

```
uint64_t Convert(uint64_t num)
{
    uint64_t m = 1000;
    uint64_t a = num / factor;
    uint64_t t = num % factor;
    uint64_t h = m * t / factor;

    return a * m + h;
}
```

Example:

```
uint64_t Convert2(uint64_t num)
{
    return num * 1000ULL / factor;
}

uint64_t Convert3(uint64_t num)
{
    return num / factor * 1000ULL;
}


int main()
{
    cout << Convert(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()) << endl;
    cout << Convert2(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()) << endl;
    cout << Convert3(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
7865257077400  <--- // The correct one //
7865257077     <--- // Value wrapped before multiplication // 
7865257077000  <--- // Low accuracy, loses remaining //
```

Answer (score 1):

Factorize your division:

```
r = 1000*(n/factor) + ((n%factor)*1000)/Factor
```

You could still run into problems if the remainder overflows (factor is large) but if factor is less than `MAX_UINT64/1000` you are ok.